# How do I amend "{:<25}" formatting in Python 2 to 3 upgrade

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.6

I'm trying to convert this python2.7 code to python3.6

```
def write_to_zip(x, zf, vocab_start):
    curr_name = "{0}_S{1}_{2}".format(x['study_name'], x['subject_id'], x['repeat_num'])
    vocab_string = x[vocab_start:].to_string(header = False, index = False).replace('\n','').encode("utf-8")
    demo_string = ("{:<25}"*(vocab_start)).format(*x[0:vocab_start].replace(r'', np.nan, regex=True))
    print(demo_string)
    string_to_write = demo_string + vocab_string
    zf.writestr("{}.txt".format(curr_name), string_to_write)
```

But I am getting the following error for `demo_string = ("{:<25}"*(vocab_start)).format(*x[0:vocab_start].replace(r'', np.nan, regex=True))`

> ('unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__', 'occurred
>   at index 0')

`x` looks something like:

```
study_name                 English L1
subject_id                          2
repeat_num                          1
completed                        True
last_modified    2019-08-05 06:57 UTC
```

and generates a `demo_string` of

```
English L1               2                        1                        1                        2019-08-05 06:57 UTC
```

`vocab_start` = 34 in this example

What do I replace{:<25} with in Python3 to get the same result?

Comment: What's the `*` in there for?

Comment: It should still work, there is something else that's the problem. It seems you have a `None` in your data and it cannot be formatted when you call the string format method. You should handle those values before you try formatting and printing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change is in the way that format strings are applied for types that don't implement `__format__`. In your case your `x` list has `None`s in it. You can either remove any `None`s (or replace them), or force all arguments to be formatted as strings.

```
# Convert `None` values
demo_string = ("{:<25}"*(vocab_start)).format(*('None' if value is None else value for value in x[0:vocab_start].replace(r'', np.nan, regex=True)))

# Force everything to be converted to a string before formatting (with !s)
demo_string = ("{!s:<25}"*(vocab_start)).format(*x[0:vocab_start].replace(r'', np.nan, regex=True))
```

NB. I don't know numpy so there may well be a better way of implementing the second option.

Comment: The second works - the first is giving me the same error.  Thank you